# Regular expression to limit occurrences of specific character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I am looking for aregular expression where I can enter a limit for the number of times a special character appears.

Example: I have to limit `*` to a maximum count of `5` in the whole text, so it should be `stack***over*f**low`.

I tried like this in my directive:

```
var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9][*]{6}/g, '');
```

But it's not working. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `/([^*]*\*[^*]*){5}/` should do the trick.

Comment: Please explain what you need to do exactly. Why replace? What is the input with corresponding output?

Comment: If user enter more than specific count say for ex : Number of count for * is 5  when user enter more than that i am replacing character blank. if you have come other concern please let me know.

Comment: @ Kelvin::  thanks for the reply. with this expression /([^*]*\*[^*]*){5}/ we can achieve to restrict max five * another query related to same if i a wanna restrict max five * and five digits how i can achieve in same expression. please do reply.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to replace, perhaps you're trying to prevent anymore asterisks from being entered? In any case, I'd recommend you expand your scope a bit and allow for some more JS to do some of the heavy lifting. If you want to prevent characters from being entered, you can check length of asterisks on every keypress event.

```
var str = 'This* is a ** test string. **';
var count = (str.match(/\*/g) || []).length;
if (count >= 5) {
  alert('doing something...')
}
else {alert(count);}
```